# Принадлежность точки к одной из секций окружности - вопрос по формуле

Tags: геометрия

Необходимо найти принадлежность некой точки к одной из 32 секций. Секции делят прямоугольник 450 на 450 как квадратный торт - в виде углов по 11.25 градуса, все лучи из центра.

Если построить окружность через отмеченную точку с центром в центре прямоугольника, то **какой формулой узнать угол между самой верхней точкой окружности и отмеченной?** Из этого легко можно будет вывести номер секции. Важно, чтобы углы больше 180 градусов считались именно в таком направлении, а не в противоположном.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: на будущее: структурируйте текст (абзацы, шрифт и т.д.). И заголовок правильно называйте. А то вам Дух все закроет (я исправил немного) . Внимание, вопрос: почему этот вопрос получил тег Python? А на С++ формула будет совсем другой?

Comment: Учел, исправил.

Comment: Посмотрите на `atan2(y, x)`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для координат x,y и центра xc, yc:

```
fi = atan2(x - xc, y - yc)
if fi < 0:
   fi += 2 * Pi
deg = degrees(fi)
```

x и y поменяны местами, чтоб учесть вашу систему координат (ноль сверху, по часовой стрелке) - если результат не тот, что ожидается - знаки ещё нужно модифицировать

Comment: Спасибо. Мне уже помог комментарий Станислава. Знаки мне в принципе не важны - это боту для расстановки приоритетов ходьбы, но разумеется с замененными будет удобнее.

Comment: Кстати, используя python решение можно сократить до fi = math.atan2(x, y)
    fi += 2 * math.pi * (fi < 0), если учесть, что координаты центра равны нулю